# Stream Video using Netcat and VLC

Tags: raspberry-pi, vlc, netcat

I'm trying to use `netcat` on Linux server to stream video to my windows client using VLC

I started running `netcat` on Linux:

```
 cat /media/HD1/myMovie.mkv | nc -l 8668
```

In VLC Windows Client I tried to:

```
Open VLC > Open network stream vlc > rtp://@serverIP:8668
```

Without success.

Comment: `VLC` has a server mode that you can use in Linux do this. Using `cat` to netcat won't make it speak the RTP protocol.

Comment: Someone told me that VLC server is heavy and i could try to use mplayer instead. Do you agree? (i'm using Raspberry pi)

Comment: `nc -l -p 5001 | mplayer -fps 31 -cache 1024 -` on the receiving side.

Comment: @ppumkin `nc: address already in use`

Comment: Port is in use by something else? try another port number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been looking for such a solution this weekend. 
Since i found one i thought to share it for future researchers.

**PC 1** = Server. The PC in my lan having my movie stored

```
$ netcat -l -p 8111 <mymovie.mp4      # -p 8111 :port 8111. Can be any port
#OR 
$ cat mymovie.mp4 |netcat -l -p 8111  # -l : listening mode
```

**PC 2** = Client. The PC connected to my TV

```
$ netcat 192.168.1.116 8111 |vlc -         # Change IP accordingly to find PC1
#OR 
$ cat </dev/tcp/192.168.1.116/8111 |vlc -  # in Bash
```

Instead of `vlc` you can use `mpv` or any other video player as soon as read from standard input is supported.

Next Weekend Task:
Serve `mymovie.mp4` to client alongside with subtitles `srt` file

Answer (score 1):

`vlc` has a stream feature to redirect video by network.
You need execute this command on server:

```
vlc -vvv zzx.rmvb  --sout '#std{access=mmsh,mux=asfh,dst=:8080}'
```

And then,you can execute this command on client:

```
mms://server_ip_address:8080
```

As the above，I use mms/mmsh to redirect video by network. Vlc support other stream methods. For example:http,udp,rtp/rtsp and so on. 
   Please take a look at the document of vlc.